# Unrecognized Android Studio version

Tags: android-studio

Unrecognized Android Studio (or Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA) version '202.7660.26.42.7486908', please retry with version 2020.3.1 or newer.

Comment: Change your classpath build Gradle version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152879/unrecognized-android-studio-or-android-support-plugin-for-intellij-idea-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unrecognized Android Studio (or Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152879/unrecognized-android-studio-or-android-support-plugin-for-intellij-idea-error)

Answer (score 34):

To solve this issue you can either open your project with android studio version 2020.3.1 or just change `Android Gradle Plugin Version` in the project stucture settings to the version that your Android Studio supports, I use Android Studio 4.2.2 so I changed the version to 4.2.2 and it works for me.[image]

Answer (score 11):

**1. Why**

It happens if the Intellij Android Support plugin version used has a lower major/minor version than the current Android Gradle plugin

**2. How**

*You have three options.*

1. Add `android.injected.studio.version.check=false` to gradle.properties to temporary stop AGP version checking
2. Upgrade Android Studio to the newest version (Maybe the Canary builds)
   [Preview builds](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) can be installed side by side with stable versions.(Sugguest)
3. Downgrade *Android Gradle Plugin Version* to fit your Android Studio

[Read More](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/ide/StudioVersions.kt?autodive=0%2F%22)

Answer (score 4):

1- change your go-to the build.gradle -> in allprojects -> repositories then change the jcenter() to mavenCentral()

2- open file ->project structure -> project -> change the Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.2.2 and gradle version to 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the main problems of this error.

1. This happens because of the Intellij android support plugin has a lower major/minor version than the Current gradle plugin.
   To fix this error please go through these steps

- open file ->project structure -> project -> change the Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.2.2 and gradle version to 7.0.2
  This step fixes my error.
  Thank You
  T